# Bootstrap grids responsive

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a 3 column layout with the code here for example. Right now when the browser window gets smaller it stacks from the 1st column on top, 2nd in the middle and then 3rd is last as expected. I want the columns to behave this way when the columns get smaller.

```
First - This column gets hidden and I have already established that in the CSS
Third - This is the first column on top. 
Second- This column is on bottom.

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">First</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">Second</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">Third</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.order-` classes for controlling the visual order of your content.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      First, but unordered
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 order-12">
      Second, but last
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 order-1">
      Third, but first
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```